# The tkinter window of my rotating cube animation does not showing anyting

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
import time

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg='black')
canvas.pack()

class Cube:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, size, colors):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.colors = colors
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.angleX, self.angleY = 0, 0
        self.update()

    def project(self, x, y, z):
        return self.x + (x * self.size) / (z + self.size), self.y + (y * self.size) / (z + self.size)

    def update(self):
        points = [[-1, -1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1, -1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [1, -1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, 1]]
        t = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 4, 5, 1], [1, 5, 6, 2], [2, 6, 7, 3], [3, 7, 4, 0], [4, 7, 6, 5]]
        self.polygons = []
        for point in points:
            x, y = self.project(point[0], point[1], point[2])
            points[points.index(point)] = [x, y]
        for triangle in t:
            p1 = points[triangle[0]]
            p2 = points[triangle[1]]
            p3 = points[triangle[2]]
            p4 = points[triangle[3]]
            self.polygons.append([p1, p2, p3, p4])

    def rotateX(self, angle):
        self.angleX += angle
        for point in [[-1, -1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1, -1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [1, -1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, 1]]:
            y = point[1]
            z = point[2]
            point[1] = y * cos(angle) - z * sin(angle)
            point[2] = z * cos(angle) + y * sin(angle)
        self.update()

    def rotateY(self, angle):
        self.angleY += angle
        for point in [[-1, -1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1, -1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [1, -1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, 1]]:
            x = point[0]
            z = point[2]
            point[0] = x * cos(angle) - z * sin(angle)
            point[2] = z * cos(angle) + x * sin(angle)
        self.update()

    def draw(self):
        for polygon in self.polygons:
            self.canvas.create_polygon(polygon, fill=self.colors[self.polygons.index(polygon)], outline='black')

colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "white", "yellow", "purple"]
cube = Cube(canvas, 250, 250, 200, colors)

while True:
    cube.rotateY(0.01)
    cube.rotateX(0.01)
    canvas.delete("all")
    cube.draw()
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

root.mainloop()
```

I don't get an errror but somehow the tkinter window stays black.
The program was written by gpt3 and I also tryed to let gpt3 fix the code by itself but it wasn't able to. I wasn't able to find the reason for the black screen jet but I asume that it is caused by the root.mainloop() function not to execute propperly. If this was the reason I would still not be able to fix it so here I am.
I hope for your help.

Philipp

Comment: Pardon my bad spelling

Comment: Your math isn't correct. Simply change outline to `white` and you see it does nothing but a white dot in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think your looop works like you expect it to
You never exit the while loop to start the main loop.

instead you might wanna try something like this:

```
def update_cube():
    cube.rotate_y(0.01)
    cube.rotate_x(0.01)
    canvas.delete("all")
    cube.draw()
    root.update()
    root.after(10, update_cube())

root.after(0, update_cube())
root.mainloop()
```

And I think there is someting wrong with your poligons in your draw method.
The attribute is supposed to hold tupples but you have multiple lists of values.
Check your self.polygons and make sure the values you put in the create_polygon method are correct. Depending on your IDE, if you tell self.canvas to be a Canvas, you might get some information about the argument error. At least in PyCharm this works.

```
def draw(self):
    for polygon in self.polygons:
        self.canvas: Canvas
        self.canvas.create_polygon(polygon, fill=self.colors[self.polygons.index(polygon)], outline='black')
```

Comment: This isn’t quite right. It needs to be `root.after(10, update_cube)`. Notice the removal of `()`

Comment: @BryanOakley you are right, I didn't catch this.

Comment: Also if you are going to use `.after`, you don't need the `root.update()`.